# Class 'Model name' not found in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

This is my controller but so that I can download excel.  The locations of the controller and the model are both the same I already checked it but still there's an error and it says that "Class "App\Item" Not Found".

```
namespace Vanguard\Http\Controllers\Web;
use Input;
use App\Item;
use DB;
use Excel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Vanguard\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Cache;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class MaatwebsiteDemoController extends Controller
{
    public function importExport()
    {
        return view('importExport');
    }
    public function downloadExcel()
    {
        $data = Item::get()->toArray();
        return Excel::create('itsolutionstuff_example', function($excel) use ($data) {
            $excel->sheet('mySheet', function($sheet) use ($data)
            {
                $sheet->fromArray($data);
            });
        })->download($type);
    }
    public function importExcel()
    {
        if(Input::hasFile('import_file')){
            $path = Input::file('import_file')->getRealPath();
            $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader){
            })->get();
            if(!empty($insert)){
                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                    $insert[] = ['title' => $value->title, 'description' => $value->description];
                }
            if(!empty($insert)){
                DB::table('items')->insert($insert);
                dd('Insert Record succesfully');
            }
            }
        }
        return back();
    }
}
```

Then this is how my Model is.

```
<?php

namespace Vanguard\App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Item extends Model
{
    public $fillable = ['title','description'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your model's FQCN is `Vanguard\App\Item`, not `App\Item`.

Comment: @gwapo, I would suggest not changing the default namespace structure unless you specifically have a reason to. Normally, Models are under the App namespace.

Comment: I changed it to that one then it says 
Class "Vanguard\App\Item" Not found

Comment: @gwapo Is your PSR4 namespacing setup correctly? What does your "autoload" section in `composer.json` look like? What does your directory structure look like?

Comment: "psr-4": {
            "Vanguard\\": "app/"
        },
      
Thats how mmy autoload in composer.json @patricus

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @gwapo Given your `psr-4` definition, your item class must be located at `app/App/Item.php`. Is it?

Comment: so instead should i put in the location instead of "Vanguard" I should put "app"?

Comment: @gwapo What is the file path for your `Item` class? What is the file path for your `MaatwebsiteDemoController` located?

Comment: @patricus /app/Http/Controllers/MaatwebsiteDemoController.php

Comment: @gwapo What about your `Item` class?

Comment: I already fixed it the Model Item is in the Models folder. Sorry my bad anyways thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `App\Item` class and your class is `Vanguard\Item`
**1. use `Vanguard\Item` Model**

```
use Input;
// use App\Item; // REMOVE that line
use Vanguard\Item; // ADD this line
use DB;
use Excel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Vanguard\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Cache;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

class MaatwebsiteDemoController extends Controller
{
    ...
}
```

**2. Modify the Model namespace.**

```
namespace Vanguard;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Item extends Model
{
    public $fillable = ['title','description'];
}
```

**3. and run `composer dump-autoload`**

Comment: you have the problem into the Model Namespace, I just read the comment in the other answer and **your autoload is `Vanguard` not `Vanguard\App`**

Comment: How to run composer dump-autoload? @Maru Amallo

Comment: yes, like you run `composer install`, `composer update` or `composer require `. 
You need to run `composer dump-autoload` or `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: Or `composer du`. :)

Answer (score 0):

issue:
Error
Class 'App\Model\ModelCustomer' not found

solved:
i solved this issue by adding s to Model become Models.

i was using "use App\Models\ModelCustomer"